# How can I add GETDATE() command on ntext field?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, getdate

I would like to add dates on ntext field.

```
UPDATE Customer SET Notes='Account has been updated'+ CAST GETDATE()
```

This is what I get when I run the query.

> "Operand type clash: datetime is incompatible with ntext"

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: As posted the syntax is invalid. However, you really need to change your datatype away from ntext. It has been deprecated for more than a decade now and is a serious pain to deal with. You should instead use nvarchar(max)...but do you really need that much storage?

Answer (score 3):

You need to cast the date as a **varchar** so it can be concatenated with the **text/varchar** you have.

```
'Account has been updated'+ CAST(GETDATE() AS varchar(20))
```

Comment: You should always specify the length of varchar instead of relying on the default.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast the result of GETDATE() to a string to get this to work. The simplest option is to do something like this:

```
UPDATE Customer SET Notes='Account has been updated'+ CAST(GETDATE() AS NVARCHAR(20))
```

However if you want control over how the date/time is formatted then use CONVERT instead:

```
UPDATE Customer SET Notes='Account has been updated'+ CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), GETDATE(), 126)
```

The 3rd parameter determines the format to use and the full list of available options for this can be seen on [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187928.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I would use CONVERT instead of CAST in this case to control the output format.

```
SELECT 'Account has been updated '+ CONVERT(varchar(20),GETDATE(),104)
```

This e.g. give me dd.mm.yyyy.

See full list here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms187928%28v=sql.120%29.aspx